# DrawerLayout and Gravity compat not included in android.support.v4

Tags: android, eclipse

So i got a problem with
 
`android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat` and
`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

It's not included in the support.v4 i checked lot of articles
about this problem but non of them helped me.

I looked for the classes of those items, but found nothing

Help me please

Comment: Both of those classes are in current versions of the Android Support Library. If you were using Android Studio or another Gradle-capable IDE, you could use `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'` to pull in the now-current version of that library, and those classes are available in it.

Comment: I dont have the gardle for the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated your ADT your Library Build Paths might have been messed up. Try the following:

Right click on Project
Build Path -> Configure Build Path
Tab: Order and Export
Make sure your Android and Android Dependencies libraries are checked
Clean & Build your Project
During my last ADT update all of them became unchecked and I had similar errors.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16783351/4069985